# Ceiling fan not receiving power when other devices are working and there is continuity in the wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

The wiring to my ceiling fan -- wiring and fan both installed by a licensed electrician in 2020 -- stopped powering the fan after I installed the switch, and I have not been able to diagnose and fix the problem. There is no light kit. (If you're curious, my original goal was to install a 3-speed fan control switch, rated for 1.5A, to control my 0.7A fan.)

I have done the following:

- Reinstalled the original switch.
- Bypassed the switch entirely (by tying together the wires entering the switch).
- Verified that there is continuity on the hot and neutral wires between the switch and the fan.
- Verified that the fan works when temporarily wired to a wall outlet.
- Checked that none of the hot or neutral wires came loose in the switch box.
  For testing purposes I temporarily attached an receptacle to the wires at the fan, and plugged in a receptacle tester. I'll be happy if and when the receptacle tester lights up.

Additional context: I am in the US, so 120V power. There are 2 sets of lights and one thermostat-controlled fan that all receive power through the same switch box, all on the same circuit, and all of which besides the ceiling fan continue to work.

I am out of hypotheses to test at this point and would gratefully welcome suggestions.

Comment: Did you take a "before" picture of the wiring? Sounds like you connected something wrong, and have kept connecting it wrong while testing/"reinstalling"/etc. if the fan keeps not working.

Comment: Show us some pics, from the switch and the fan box